# "Full body massage", or "Whole body massage"?

Tags: word-choice

Is one of "Full body massage" or "Whole body massage" more commonly used than the other, especially by experts?

A onelook.com search only gave references to Urban Dictionary (user generated content) and Wikipedia (talking about a film).

Comment: Have you checked with ngrams?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full+body+massage%2Cwhole+body+massage&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfull%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfull%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFull%20Body%20Massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFull%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhole%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0  ...I wouldn't say this is the end of the story, since someone may have thoughts about overtones implied in the two statements, but it is a good starting point.

Comment: @Adam thanks. It seems odd that usage has spiked in the past few decades if it's talking about conventional massages, though, as I assume the demand for conventional massages would remain fairly steady.

Comment: Demand for a service isn't always going to track exactly with the phrase people use to describe it.

Comment: _"I assume the demand for conventional massages would remain fairly steady."_  Interesting: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=massage&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmassage%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmassage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMassage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMASSAGE%3B%2Cc0  Looks like there was somesort of heyday in the mentioning of massages about 100 years ago, then it dropped off until about 25 years ago.  Talking about massage was apparently not cool in 1950.  No wonder Frenchy dropped out of Beauty school instead of Massage school.

Comment: "Foot massages" were not mentioned at all 100 years ago, but "leg massages" were almost half of current levels - as high as "shoulder massage" before dropping off.  "Neck massage" has an even more dramatic peak back then - Especially (oddly) in all caps: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neck+massage&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cneck%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BNECK%20MASSAGE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bneck%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNeck%20Massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNeck%20massage%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Full body massage*** is the more commonly used term.

[Citation from comments is located here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full%20body%20massage%2Cwhole%20body%20massage&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfull%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfull%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFull%20Body%20Massage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFull%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhole%20body%20massage%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Can you give a citation for this, perhaps the one in question comments, so this answer will stand alone?

Comment: I had a look at example citations for "full body massage" between 2002 and 2007, and they come from experts on massage, so I'm happy with this answer.